# Remote icon on Galaxy S6 Edge

Tags: samsung

I suddenly have a new strange symbol on my S6 Edge screen and have no idea what it is but if I touch it, it locks my phone up. The only way I can get it unlocked is by swiping the edge. I'm able to move it around but it appeared while away from and charging my phone so I wasn't accidentally playing around with settings or anything. It appears like a remote perhaps.

What is it?

Edit: I'm with Bell, using version 5.1.1 and have attached an enlarged a screenshot (it's the same size as a Messenger Chat Head).

> [image: remote icon]

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I always have Hotspot off, I double checked to be sure and it is off. It did randomly disappear for a few hours and then reappeared again for a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based from [a thread on Android Central](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/640046-little-remote-control-icon-my-samsung-note-4-screen.html), it's an icon from [Peel Smart Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tv.peel.app) app.

[uestraven](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/640046-little-remote-control-icon-my-samsung-note-4-screen.html#post4982115) recommended to disable the app to remove it.

> [...]. I just figured it out. It's Peel Smart Remote app. You have to disable it.

It seems the icon was added on the latest update as [IAmSixNine](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/640046-little-remote-control-icon-my-samsung-note-4-screen.html#post4982188) wrote,

> I updated the Peel Smart Remote app on my GS6 and after I rebooted the phone, it showed up on mine as well. Pretty annoying if you ask me that they did that. I don't and have never used the app and for them to update the app and then force that on me is pretty lame.

[image: screenshot with overlay icon]

<sup>Screenshot on Galaxy Note 4, courtesy of Realityhurts82</sup>

Comment: Interesting. Can you share the methodology you used to pin-point the app? I guess I'm using archaic methods. :-)

Comment: @Firelord I googled "samsung galaxy s6 remote icon" and the first result was [a thread on AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/640122-little-grey-round-remote-icon-popped-up-my-note4.html), from there, the second reply linked to [another thread on AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/640046-little-remote-control-icon-my-samsung-note-4-screen.html)