# Peel remote on S6

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

I saw [this thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136209/remote-icon-on-galaxy-s6-edge) where this issue was resolved for the S6 Edge. I have the S6, so closing it from the Edge is obviously not an option here. My screen is completely locked up. I can't even answer phone calls. I'm having to use my table to send texts via MightyText, but I can't make calls, take pictures, or even power off the phone. How can I fix this? My current plan is to let the battery die and then reboot it, but I'd really like to be able to fix this sooner.

I can't comment on the other thread because I don't have enough points. I know this isn't worth another new thread, but I was locked out of the other.

I'm running stock Android, whatever the latest release was for the S6. Help!

Comment: If you hold the power button for 30 seconds (or until it reboots) does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down power + vol down + home at the same time for about 15 seconds. Let it reboot, if it doesnt start rebooting, simply press power button. You just did a force shutdown

(I have a S6)