# Remote icon disabled my phone!

Tags: remote-control, samsung-galaxy-s-6

That same icon appeared on my phone and when I clicked on it to see what it was my screen got darker and it wont let me click on anything else or turn off my phone. I have no idea how to remove this peel smart app mentioned if it is not letting me click on anything or turn off the phone, Please help.

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136209/remote-icon-on-galaxy-s6-edge/136272?s=1|0.3895#136272

Answer (score 0):

Press the volume down button and power button at the same time. Options should come up to restart phone. Then disable Peel remote app.